# How can I output Python to a Bash script and preserve spaces?

Tags: python, arrays, bash, stdout

I have a Python script which, at any point in its execution, may print out text. I'm running that Python script from a Bash script - I want the Bash to be able to capture all of the output from the Python and store it in an array.

So say this is my Python:

```
print("foo")
print("bar baz")
print("")
print("moo")
```

(And there could well be code before and after each of these print statements.) I would want Bash to run the Python script, grab the output and pop it into an array like so:

```
var=('foo' 'bar' 'baz' '' 'moo')
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

var=($(python pyspace.py))
echo "${var[@]}" 
echo "${#var[@]}"
for i in "${!var[@]}"; do
    echo "${var[$i]}";
done
```

And here's the output when I run the Bash:

```
foo bar baz moo
4
foo
bar
baz
moo
```

The problem is, of course, the space. I've run into this problem before, and learned from [this answer on Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622758/428326) that I need to properly escape variables with double quotes to ensure that empty string items will show up in Bash arrays.

But that hasn't worked here. Just for comparison, when I run this code:

```
arr=(aa '' b 'bb')
echo "${arr[@]}"
echo "${#arr[@]}"
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo $i
done
```

I get this output:

```
aa  b bb
4
aa

b
bb
```

So I believe the problem comes from when I call the Python script - I don't think it's handling the whitespace properly.

I *could* make the Python so that it outputs a single list of everything it wants to print, like this `['foo', 'bar', '', 'baz']` etc. and use `tr` to get rid of the extra characters, but that gives me less flexibility in how I write the Python. I'd like the Python to be able to `print` from anywhere, and the Bash will correctly add the output to an array.

How can I set up the Bash and Python so that Python can pass empty strings to Bash from anywhere in the code, and the latter will recognise the empty string as a valid array element?

Comment: Your problem is in the line `var=($(python pyspace.py))`. That's an antipattern, don't do `array=( $(anything) )` ever. Instead, `readarray -t array < <(anything)`

Comment: See [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29).

Comment: you don't have space in `''`  but empty string.

Comment: And `echo "$i"`, not `echo $i`.

Comment: BTW, in general, `printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"` is a better way to print each array element to a different line of output.

Comment: Also, note that double quotes only have effect for suppressing string-splitting when they're in a context that treats them as syntax, not when they're in a context that treats them as data. That means double quotes in the output of `pyspace.py` are just another character with no special behavior.

Comment: ...that distinction is also at the heart of [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (a very different thing than the above BashPitfalls link despite having the same number).